Error: No module named 'Processing' when using PyQGIS
I'm a beginner trying to work with PyQGIS and integrate QGIS processing algorithms into my Python scripts. I’m currently using Visual Studio Code as my IDE and trying to run a script that utilizes QGIS's processing module.
I have set up my environment and added the QGIS Python paths to sys.path, but I encounter the following error when I try to import the Processing module:
ProcessingModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Processing'


Here's a snippet of my code where the error occurs:


import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins')

from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()


I have initialized QGIS properly, but it seems that the Processing module is not being recognized.
Could someone help me understand what might be going wrong or how to properly set up the environment for PyQGIS? A

This seems like a cross-site dupe of https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/130337/257239
